# How to fix 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.categories.concat is not a function' in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux for state management and while trying to add a new data entry I am getting this error.

The following is the code for my reducer

```js
import { ADD_CATEGORY_SUCCESS } from "../actions/type";
const initialState = {
  categories: [],
  status: null,
  statusType: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action.payload);
      console.log(state.categories);
      return {
        categories: state.categories.concat(action.payload),
        status: 200,
        statusType: "addCategory"
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The console.log's for the first one returned an object and for the second one an array of objects. The data is getting added on the database. So I cant understand where the problem is.

Comment: Show how `state.categories` looks like, its not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm why don't you try this, I've only changed the concat to spread operation

```
import {ADD_CATEGORY_SUCCESS } from '../actions/type';
const initialState = {
categories: [],
status: null,
statusType: null
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) { 
    case ADD_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action.payload);
      console.log(state.categories);
      return {
         categories: [...state.categories.categories,action.payload],
         status:200,
         statusType: "addCategory"
      }
     default:
       return state;
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried that but this was the error that i got ** Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance **

Comment: Ok can you just show what you got when you consoled

Comment: {categories: Array(22)}

Comment: {_id: "5d3ef97d2287d700179b733f", name: "HEllllo", register_date: "2019-07-29T13:49:49.930Z", __v: 0}

Comment: wait (state.categories) gave you  {categories: Array(22)} ? then can you log state.categories.categories

Comment: Great, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

In case `state.categories` is an array:

[`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) accepts an array while `action.payload` is an object.

In your case you can try one of those solutions:

```
return {
  // Concat
  categories: state.categories.concat([action.payload]),

  // Spead operator
  caregories: [...state.categoris, action.payload],
  ...
}
```

Comment: i had no luck even after trying these 2 methods